# Unable to open Synaptic package manager in 12.04

Tags: package-management

I have Synaptic package manager installed in my Ubuntu 12.04 version .

While locating the same in Dash and by single clicking on it , I am not able to open the same.

Comment: can you please try the following: open a Terminal, type `synaptic` and confirm by pressing ENTER. You can open a Terminal by searching for it in the Dash, or by pressing STRG+ALT+T. Does this bring up Synaptic? If not, what message does the Terminal give you?

Answer (score 1):

First remove synaptic by

```
sudo apt-get --purge synaptic
```

Reinstall it

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```